How do I auto hide other object while editing a selected object
i've been working with almost 30 iterations, and i want to be able to compare them in object mode, but hiding and unhiding some object are annoying because i also have other boolean happening. what i really want is to be able to work on my edit mode, wihtout seeing the other object that i dont select, and as soon as i hit tab and back to object mode, i will be able to compare them all. thanks!

Perhaps selecting the object you want to edit then going into Local View using the Numpad Slash Key will do the job. This will hide all other objects in the 3D viewport until you hit the Numad Slash key again.

Why don't you use Local view? The advantage over hiding and unhiding is, if you don't do it manual, unhiding with Alt+H reveals all objects even if you want to keep some hidden. Switching to Local view will only keep the selected object(s) visible and when you switch back, individual visibility settings of other objects are unchanged. Local view is Numpad / to toggle on/off. @3fingeredfrog Oops, I typed my comment a few seconds too long ;) I forgot an advantage, you can rotate and zoom your Local view as you need it for editing, but when you go back the view is like before.
